# Selenium.get() не работает python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Первый раз работаю с Selenium. Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeAdr = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeAdr)
browser.get('http://vk.com')
```

Chrome успешно открывается, но метод get не выполняется, вместо этого вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/����/PycharmProjects/BurgerScam/BurgeHuyrger.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeAdr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

И я совсем не понимаю, что с этим делать. Так же я пытался использовать вместо Chrome Firefox, но увы без результата, так как в Firefox выдает ошибку

> Не удалось загрузить ваш профиль Firefox

Comment: тебе не хром надо запускать а chromedriver.exe

Comment: И пользователь желательно не на кириллице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы используете обычный exeшник браузера, он не подойдет. Для тестирования нужно скачать специальный драйвер, в вашем случае - [chromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

затем указать к нему путь -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/путь/до/драйвера')
```

И не забудьте после выполнения всех нужных действия закрыть chrome

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

иначе кэш не удалится и папка temp очень быстро скушает всю память.